# What is the sequence/chord/key used to backspace an Emacs Command

Tags: doom, backspace

In Doom Emacs, I pressed `SPC` then pressed `p` instead of `o`. If I press Backspace key then it becomes `DEL` instead of backspacing `p`. This means Backspace key is one of the chords. How am I supposed to do a Backspace for the commands? What is the key or step that I need to do for backspacing commands in Doom Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to undo a key when entering a sequence of keys.
Usually one would enter `C-g` to `(keyboard-quit)` and reenter the sequence
because sequences are typically short.

Documentation for `keyboard-quit`:

> Signal a quit condition.
>
> During execution of Lisp code, this character causes a quit directly.
> At top-level, as an editor command, this simply beeps.

I'm a fan of Doom, but not a user. So I'm not sure what the idomatic way to do
this is in Doom. However, after greping through their repo (in the develop branch), I found the following:

https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/2731685095d1e6101b3215aa689426e1834ce00f/core/core-keybinds.el#L61

```el
;;
;;; Universal, non-nuclear escape

;; `keyboard-quit' is too much of a nuclear option. I wanted an ESC/C-g to
;; do-what-I-mean. It serves four purposes (in order):
;;
;; 1. Quit active states; e.g. highlights, searches, snippets, iedit,
;;    multiple-cursors, recording macros, etc.
;; 2. Close popup windows remotely (if it is allowed to)
;; 3. Refresh buffer indicators, like git-gutter and flycheck
;; 4. Or fall back to `keyboard-quit'
;;
;; And it should do these things incrementally, rather than all at once. And it
;; shouldn't interfere with recording macros or the minibuffer. This may require
;; you press ESC/C-g two or three times on some occasions to reach
;; `keyboard-quit', but this is much more intuitive.

;; ... elided

(global-set-key [remap keyboard-quit] #'doom/escape)
```

I think maybe you can quit a sequence with `Esc`, but might have to press it
more than once or `C-g` to nuke it.

Please try it and let me know!

Comment: The ESC key and C-g works when I use `SPC` modifier. What about `C-c` and `C-x` and etc modifiers.

Comment: @LordVictor The `C-g` is like a universal quit command in Emacs. To stop a chord sequence with started with `C-c` or `C-x`, the `C-g` should also work. I imagine `Esc` should work too in Doom.

For me, in Emacs, it says `C-c C-g is undefined`. I don't have the fancy Esc functionality that Doom does though.

Comment: For me too, it says `C-c C-g` is undefined. Also this too `C-c ESC` Atleast it removes all the previous key strokes so that we can continue.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to 'undo' a key when reading a key sequence.  As indicated by the `read-key-sequence` docstring, `C-g` is intentionally not special in that situation -- but `C-g` is usually never bound to anything other than 'quit' type commands in any keymap, so you can generally get away with using it to 'cancel' a key sequence, as it'll either do a 'quit' action, or simply not be found (hence ending the sequence harmlessly).